# How can I configure ckanext-archiver plugin for CKAN (dockerized) to make it work?

Tags: redis, celery, ckan

I'm using the Docker approach from [here](https://github.com/okfn/docker-ckan) and I can't find a way to make the archiver with report and qa plugins fully working.

Apparently, the archiver plugin is not executed (the tasks for archiver update are launched and listed in the queue but not executed - don't see any archive created). 
The configs for celery in production.ini are as follow:

```
# Before [app:main]
[app:celery]
BROKER_URL = redis://redis:6379
RESULT_BACKEND = redis://redis:6379
BROKER_BACKEND = redis
BROKER_HOST = redis://redis/1
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = redis
REDIS_HOST = redis
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_DB = 0
REDIS_CONNECT_RETRY = True
```

and the configs for Archiver

```
# Archiver Settings
ckanext-archiver.archive_dir=/var/lib/ckan/storage/resource_cache
ckanext-archiver.cache_url_root=http://ckan:5000/resource_cache
ckanext-archiver.max_content_length=50000000
```

For all 3 plugins the db schema is initiated. 
Another issue, the report info in the dataset detail page is not visible

[image: Screenshot]

Any suggestion for the right way to configure the archiver plugin will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, did you included the archiver plugin in the Docker setup? If not follow this [Docker](https://github.com/keitaroinc/ckanext-datagovmk/blob/master/Dockerfile#L44) as an example.

Next, the archiver can be triggered by adding a dataset with a resource or updating a resource URL using ckanext-archiver command. Please check [using archiver docs](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-archiver#using-archiver).

You can also check these sh scripts, to run as cron jobs that are executing the archiver and then generate reports:

- [archiver.sh](https://github.com/keitaroinc/ckanext-datagovmk/blob/944b645a9f45d863ab6d22edc00e2d6bca0aeeca/scripts/cron_jobs/archiver.sh)
- [report.sh](https://github.com/keitaroinc/ckanext-datagovmk/blob/944b645a9f45d863ab6d22edc00e2d6bca0aeeca/scripts/cron_jobs/report.sh)